# Do dense topological subgroups always have the same finite quotients as their underlying bigger topological subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups, profinite-groups

**Definition**: Let $G$ be a topological group. We call $G$ a **finite quotient** of $G$ if there exists a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $H = G/N$ and $H$ is finite.

Let $G'$ be a dense subgroup of $G$.

**Question**: *Do $G$ and $G'$ have the same finite quotients?*

**Observations and remarks**: In some notes I found some examples where this is true, e.g. for $G' = \mathbb{Z} \subset G = \hat{\mathbb{Z}} = \varprojlim{\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}$ and $G' = W_K \subset G = G_K = \operatorname{Gal}(\bar{K}/K)$ where $K$ denotes a local field, $G_K$ the absolute Galois group and $W_K$ the Weil group. But there the authors have never given any proofs, so I don't know if this holds in general. My knowledge on topological groups is also not worth mentioning as I have no clue what kind of arguments would be helpful. It was just something that made me suspicious.

Could you please help me answering my question? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe you want $N$ to be a **closed** normal subgroup in your definition?

Comment: @MoisheCohen: I'm not sure. What would happen then? Would that make the statement true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, $S^1$ has a dense subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ but $S^1$ has no nontrivial finite quotients.

What is special about the case of $\mathbb{Z}$ and the profinite integers is that the latter is the [profinite completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group#Profinite_completion) of the former.

Comment: Could you please explain why $S^1$ has no nontrivial finite quotient? Unfortunately, I could not figure it out by myself yet.

Comment: @Diglett: $S^1$ is divisible, which means for every $g \in S^1$ and every positive integer $n$ we can find $h \in S^1$ such that $g = h^n$. Now show that 1) quotients of divisible groups are divisible, and 2) the only divisible finite group is the trivial group.